# How to understand the meaning of the new HISTOGRAMS in tensorboard with TF 0.11?

Tags: tensorflow, histogram, tensorboard

There are some screenshots of tensorboard from TF-0.11:

[Distributions(which is the old version of "HISTOGRAMS")](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YNaJ.png)

[New version of "HISTOGRAMS"(overlay)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SA7e.png)

This is from the example mnist_with_summaries.py.

The network is:

input: (batchsize * 784)

layer1: preactivations=input*weights+bias    weights->(784*500),bias->(500)

```
    activations=relu(preactions)
```

dropout:...

layer2:...

crossentropy:...

My problem is that i cant understant the meaning of this new “HISTOGRAMS”...
In the second screenshot, the "step 16" of fig "layer1/bias(train)" has the point (0.0986,121).Does that means that there are 121 bias parameters whose value is 0.0986?

But this meaning looks can not be generalized to other fig in “HISTOGRAMS” like "layer1/activations(train)".I don't think layer1 has more than 500 activations values，but the plot has a point with a number of "3.00e+4".

Comment: Not sure if these histograms are still used; some helpful information about current Tensorflow histograms is available here: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/tensorboard_histograms